# Is there a way to send reminder emails for a collector using the Survey Monkey API?

Tags: email, surveymonkey

I see in the SurveyMonkey API there is the send_Flow call, that allows you to create an email collector and an email for it. Is there a way through the API to send a reminder email for an existing email collector? If not, does SurveyMonkey have any plans to add that functionality to the API in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to send a reminder through the API. `send_flow` doesn't even send an email from the API; it just sets it up and requires a user to complete sending the email from SurveyMonkey's user interface (that's why it's a "flow").

It's possible that the ability to send reminders will be added to the API after sending programmatically is possible, but it's impossible to make and guarantees on future functionality or timing of API features.